# How to get the content in MySQL through email?

Tags: mysql, html, database, email

I have a textbox and a button in html page. When i click a button, whatever the text entered will be stored in the database. But i want the same text to my email Id as well, How can i achieve this? Please help..

Comment: You find the variables in your database insertion program, then use them when you call some mail sending function that is appropriate to the unspecified programming language that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In your submit event,

**First** : Database store script;

**Second** : mail function;